# "לְחֹדֶשׁ שְׁנֵים עָשָׂר" in the Megillah and Al Hanisim

Tags: calendar, purim, al-hanissim, megillat-esther

As I was reading Al Hanisim this year, something odd struck me "לְחֹדֶשׁ שְׁנֵים עָשָׂר" - the 12th  month. What  struck me was that  this year is a leap year so we actually celebrated Purim in the 13th month Adar Sheini (bet).
     What is the significance of mentioning לְחֹדֶשׁ שְׁנֵים עָשָׂר, it seems to imply Purim should be in the 12th month - which halachically is not so....?

Also, based on [Why is Purim on Adar II during a leap year?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/35519/why-is-purim-on-adar-ii-during-a-leap-year), thanks @Yishai, I would like to add to my question -Why does the megillah emphasize  "bi-Shloshah Asar le-Chodesh Shneim Asar" - that Purim was in the 12th month?

Comment: Highly related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/35519/why-is-purim-on-adar-ii-during-a-leap-year

Comment: Why would you assume Purim happened in a non-leap year? The Yerushalmi says otherwise.

Comment: For what it's worth, neither Rambam's _Seder ha-Tefilah_ ([Mechon Mamre edition](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/2700.htm#24)) nor [Siddur Rav Saadiah Gaon](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20685&pgnum=316) have "_bi-Shloshah Asar le-Chodesh Shneim Asar, Hu Chodesh Adar_" in _Al ha-Nisim_, but [Seder Rav Amram Gaon](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42696&pgnum=80) does have it.

Comment: @DoubleAA please quote the yerushalmi - based on ( thanks @Yishai) http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/35519/why-is-purim-on-adar-ii-during-a-leap-year, it seems difficult to accept literally.

Comment: Isn't your added question a re-wording of the question you linked to?

Comment: @TamirEvan That question asks why we celebrate Purim in the 2nd Adar not the first. My question ( based on the fact that we celebrate Purim in the 2nd) is why does the megillah make mention of the fact that Adar is the 12th month, if it has no ramifications to our celebrating it. Do you think an answer to the 1st Q will answer mine - please post if yes.

Comment: (1) That question asks why we celebrate Purim in the 2nd Adar not the first **because of the verses that make a point of mentioning it being in the twelfth month**. You're basically asking the same question the other way round. (2) What if I have an answer to your first question, and find the answer(s) posted to the question there equally satisfactory (or unsatisfactory), and have no answer of my own to it? (3) At the very least, your second question has no direct link to the 'wording of _Al ha-Nisim_' question, and should be asked separately.

Comment: @DoubleAA is referring to the *Y'rushalmi* on *M'gilla* 1:5: ר' לוי בשם רבי חמא בר חנינה אותה השנה היתה מעוברת מה טעמה (אסתר ג) מיום ליום ומחדש לחדש שנים עשר הוא חדש אדר. The *Korban haEida* and the *P'nei Moshe* comment (ad loc.) that the miracle happened in Adar II. The *Korban HaEida* explains the *Y'rushalmi*'s reading of the verse: "To that which is annually the twelfth month, but which is now the thirteenth month". The *P'nei Moshe* indicates that this is hinted by the verse's phrasing "from month to month", which suggests that the usual 12th month was switched that year to be the 13th.

Comment: This question is very confusing.  Are you asking about the text of the Megillah?  Are you asking about the text of 'Al HaNisim?  Are you asking about leap years?

Comment: @SethJ Thank you for your comment. please let me know if the  edited version is written better

Answer (score 2):

In Megilas Taanis towards the [end of the 12th chapter](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=33153&st=%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9F%20%D7%91%D7%99%D7%9F%20%D7%90%D7%93%D7%A8%20%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9F&pgnum=249), <sup>(or page פז in the Oz VeHadar edition)</sup> the Eshel Avraham says that the Rosh in Nedarim (פ"ח סי' ב) says that **both Adars are considered as a single month** - גופיה דשני אדרים כחד חשיב להו.

In that case, Purim falls in the *very long* 12th month, even in a leap year.

The context is a discussion of which is the *real* Adar, with regards to not fasting.

Other opinions include the idea that the first Adar is considered like Shvat (with regards to fasting).

Answer (score -1):

The point of saying לחודש שנים עשר is that in those days the months were still called by their number. The names of the month, which originated in Bavel, did not yet completely substitute the original format of numbers. Additionally, Haman made his Pur with twelve cards for the twelve months and he picked out the twelfth. This is why it is significant to say, the twelfth.

Comment: Megilas Esther is one of the books brought in the yerushalmi  as being after name change took hold.

Comment: @HaLeiVi,  Seriously? The Megilla says 8 times _Chodesh Adar_, once _Chodesh Nisan_, once _Chodesh Sivan_ and once _Chodesh Teveth_ and you claim _those days the months were still called by their number_??

Comment: @DannySchoemann First of all, I gave two answers. Second, I said 'did not yet **completely** substitute the original format of numbers'. The names did come _from_ Bavel but you don't adopt something the first day you're introduced to it. They were Babylonian names of the months. Although we adopted it, this is something that happens gradually. Yechezkel Hanavi, in Bavel, only used numbers. The Megilla already calls them by these names but it is not completely replaced.

Comment: @DannySchoemann And if you'd notice, every time the Megilla mentions the Babylonian name it first calls it by its number. לחדש השלישי הוא חדש סיון, which proves my point. The same is done in Zecharia, which is from the same period.

Comment: `dditionally, Haman made his Pur with twelve cards for the twelve months and he picked out the twelfth. This is why it is significant to say, the twelfth.` Source?

Comment: @mevaqesh The Maharal writes that in Ohr Chadash, perhaps based on the system used in doling out the land to the tribes.

Comment: As always, sources should be included in the answer itself; not in comments.