# Shemona Ushloshim Ushlosh Meyot - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows three hundred thirty eight?

### שמונה ושלושים ושלוש מאות - מי יודע?‏

The traditional Passover song ["Echad - mi yodeya"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echad_Mi_Yodea) implies a possible presupposition that there is a Jewish significance to be found for each [natural number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number). Accordingly, there is an [ongoing series](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) on Mi Yodeya that is attempting to unearth significant Judaism facts about each number, in sequence.

What significant Judaism facts are there about the number 338? The more significant within Judaism and the more intrinsically dependent on the value 338, the stronger the answer. Please include sources for your information wherever possible, as with all other answers on this site.

The fact that some word's gematria happens to coincide with this number is barely a weak whisper of substance. Send answers containing only lazy gematria somewhere else.

Comment: Nu..................

Comment: @DoubleAA, I don't feel like accepting either answer.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers `:-P`

Comment: The Gematria of the Shem HaVaya (26) times the Yud Gimmel Middot (13) equals 338 (but that's lazy Gematria).

Comment: How about now ?

Comment: @DoubleAA I like your answer. I just want to take a minute to learn your sources before I accept it. Yeyasher kochacha.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

338 is the number of Attributes of Mercy mentioned on Yom Kippur. ([Tur OC 620](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%98%D7%95%D7%A8_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%9B), [Kitzur Yalkut Yosef 595:32](http://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Shulkhan_Aruch_Yalkut_Yosef.1.595.32))

(5 sets at Maariv + 5 at Shacharit + 7 at Musaf + 6 at Mincha + 3 at Ne'ilah = 26 * 13 = 338)

Answer (score 7):

R' Yaakov Asher Feldman, head of the Mateh Aharon Kollel at Yeshivas Shomrei Emunim in Jerusalem, writing in the *Kovetz Bais Aharon V'Yisrael* ([#81 - page 111](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=13117&st=&pgnum=111&hilite=)), says that when Haman selected the lottery to see on which day to eradicate the Jews in came out on the 338th day of the year, which was the 13th of Adar.

Comment: I'm sorry that I didn't post this question yesterday!

Comment: @IsaacMoses The 338th day of this year was two days ago on 12 Adar because this year there was a 30th of Cheshvan. How Kovetz Bais Aharon V'Yisrael 81 knows that the year of Purim was a Kisidran (and also [not a leap year](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/36440/%d7%9c%d6%b0%d7%97%d6%b9%d7%93%d6%b6%d7%a9%d7%81-%d7%a9%d6%b0%d7%81%d7%a0%d6%b5%d7%99%d7%9d-%d7%a2%d6%b8%d7%a9%d6%b8%d7%82%d7%a8-in-the-megillah-and-al-hanisim#comment94852_36440)) is unclear to me.

Comment: @DoubleAA, Megillat Ester specifically refers to Adar as the 12th month, IIRC. Your other complaint with the source still holds.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt The Yerushalmi (Megila 1:5) says it was in the 13th month of a leap year, so both complaints hold.

Comment: @DoubleAA, R' Feldman's source that Haman did a day-of-the-year selection, [Ya'arot Devash](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?sits=1&req=14492&st=%u05d2%u05d5%u05e8%u05dc), doesn't specify that it came out 338 but in describing the process says "If the lot with something like '340' written on it came up in his hand, then the day-count would also be in Adar." So, it looks like 338 here is a back-calculation by R' Feldman. Ya'arot Devash, FWIW, also describes the process in terms of a 354-day year.

Comment: ... So, there's good reason to believe that #338 is "*lav davka*" in this source. Still +1 from me since it's an actual use of the number and nicely seasonal. I'll hold off on accepting this answer for now, though.

Comment: Just because the answer is about purim - 338 is gematria bepurim - "with lots", so with lots (338) picked day 338 (I know you dont want gematria but here it fit so nicely with @Gershon Gold's answer)

Answer (score 3):

United Nations Security Council Resolution S/902, July 15, 1948, urging a ceasefire in the Israeli war of independence, was passed at the 338th meeting of the Security Council.

(Weak, I know.)

Comment: Lehavdil, it's a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

338 are the number of perakim in the masechtos included in the Daf Yomi cycle: Berachos, all of Moed, all of Nashim, all of Nezikin except for Avos, all of Kodshim, and Niddah. Link to the breakdown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfG2b.png).